# Table overflowy-index with HTML2PDF

Tags: php, html2pdf

I have a table which receives products.

When my table has more than 16 rows, my table overlaps my footer.

[Here is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lscqm.png)

My code is:

```
<?php require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

ob_start(); require_once 'cotizador.php';  $html = ob_get_clean();


$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'es', 'true', 'UTF-8',array(0, 0, 0, 0)); $html2pdf->writeHTML($html); $html2pdf->writeHTML($html); $html2pdf->output('cotizacion-valmex.pdf');
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you resze your window? What if you zoom out (`Ctrl` `-`)

Comment: nothing changes